# mportError When Importing from Installed data_preprocessing Module in Python

Tags: python, package, data-preprocessing

I'm encountering an ImportError while attempting to import several items from the data_preprocessing module in Python. My code includes imports of various libraries and specific functions/constants from data_preprocessing. Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
import os
import sys
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

from data_preprocessing import ANSWER_COLS, TARGET_COLS, clean_raw_data, add_features, clean_data_fn
```

However, when I run the script, I receive the following error message:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'ANSWER_COLS' from 'data_preprocessing' (/Users/xxxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/data_preprocessing/__init__.py)
```

I have already installed the data_preprocessing package using pip. Despite this, I am unsure why I am facing this import error. Could someone help me understand what might be going wrong here?

Comment: `data_preprocessing` package does not have any of these: `ANSWER_COLS, TARGET_COLS, clean_raw_data, add_features, clean_data_fn`.